# MySQL ODBC Debugging to myodbc.sql overwrites file instead of appending new queries

Tags: mysql, debug, odbc, overwrite

I am using the MySQL ODBC driver on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit box. I enabled the debug feature on the odbc driver using the ODBC administrator at %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe It does write queries to the c:\myodbc.sql file, but each time a new query appears it overwrites the file with the new query instead of appending the query to file each time a query is run. I made sure Tracing is off as well. I'm not sure what to do here. Is this normal behavior? I used the ODBC driver off of the MySQL website. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok This seems to be only a problem with the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver on a 64-Bit windows. On a 32-bit Windows 2003 Server R2 the myodbc.sql file writes correctly and the queries append correctly as well. I just moved my application to use that Windows 32-bit Server instead.